# Google Sheets QUERY statement: order by average

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have [this Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QNcCbg6nfkjbyxxm9_To8BUcNnWGTjCS4UDcLYDeRW8/edit#gid=897985113) with a query formula in it. I am trying to use the query to display an average 1-5 satisfaction rating for each `program`. This script I adapted [from Info Inspired](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/group-and-average-unique-column-in-google-sheets/) - see "formula 1" - is basically working using the following formula in cell A2:

```
=query(ArrayFormula('Form Responses 1'!B2:E),"Select B,Avg (E) group by B label Avg(E)''")
```

However, this is displaying the results **ordered alphabetically by `program`**.

[image: spreadsheet showing rating per program]

**How can I order the output by the average rating currently in column B of the image?**

I tried using the [`order by` clause](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#order-by) as in:

```
=query(ArrayFormula('Form Responses 1'!B2:F),"Select B,Avg (F) group by B label Avg(F)'' order by Avg(F)")
```

and

```
=query(ArrayFormula('Form Responses 1'!B2:F),"Select B,Avg (F) group by B label Avg(F) order by Avg(F)''")
```

but both gave me:

> Error Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "order" "order "" at line 1, column 44. Was expecting one of:  "format" ... "options" ... "," ...

I am not sure what the `''` is doing, but the first query mentioned only works with it in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it like this:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA('Form Responses 1'!B2:E), 
 "select B,Avg(E) group by B label Avg(E)''", 0), "order by Col2 asc", 0)
```

`''` is literally nothing eg. empty label

[image: 0]